# Algolia search with attribute name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algolia

Data on algolia is like this

```
objectID:3464542
Type:"Accelerator"
Country:"Germany"
City:null
Name:"ProsiebenSat1 Accelerator Batch #8"
```

I want to search any name which are in Germany. How I do that?

When I do `Contact.raw_search("Batch")`, I get all records even whose name include this even non-German. I want to get all those which are of specific country.

Comment: No one has any answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do so, you'll first need to put the `Country` attribute in your `attributesForFaceting` list. You can do that using the REST API, your client of choice or from the Algolia Dashboard. Using the later one, go to the `Indices` page, select your index and click on the `Display` tab. Here, you could add your `Country` field to the `Attributes for faceting` list. After that, click on save and your index will be rebuild.

Now, your index is ready to filter the search queries according to the country you want. To perform the search query, you can use (using the Ruby client):

```
Contact.search("Batch", {
    facets: ["Country"],
    facetFilters: ["Country:Germany"]
})
```

For more informations about faceting, here is a quick intro from the [FAQ](https://www.algolia.com/doc/faq/searching/what-is-faceting) and a more detailed guide in the [documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/search/filtering-faceting).